# How to install grafana plugins?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana

I have installed grafana using helm chart.I wanted to add pie chart plugin.So
installed grafana plugin with command `kubectl exec -it kube-prometheus-stack-chart-grafana-9dc44fc4b-ndbpt -n syg-monitoring -c grafana grafana-cli plugins install grafana-piechart-panel`
so its installed.

```
installed from: https://grafana.com/api/plugins/grafana-piechart-panel/versions/1.6.1/download
into: /var/lib/grafana/plugins

✔ Installed grafana-piechart-panel successfully
```

But whenever i visit my dashboard, unable to see plugin. Is there any addintional things to done ? please guide. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to run `service grafana-server restart`.

If you're using [this](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/grafana) grafana helm chart, you might as well just add the plugins you need in the `plugins` parameter. See [this](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/grafana-6.32.12/charts/grafana/values.yaml#L482)

This will help you in automating stuff and not rely on manual `kubectl exec` runs post chart installation.